# Automatically getting the path of a folder in listview via its position

Tags: android, file, listview, copy, external

there is a listview of all the folders of external storage in my xml file. when user clicks on any folder it allows him to add a file in that folder in my program. when user clicks on that folder it should automatically get the path of that folder as destination to store that file.user can give source folder path via browse and select.. is there any way i can do that by getting position of that folder in listview? um using following code to copy the file from source folder to destination folder

```
        public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
                 FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
                 FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
                 FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
                 FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
                 inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
                 inStream.close();
                 outStream.close();
             }
```

i used this code to show all the folders within my app directory(ABC) in external storage

```
                        try {
            ListView lv;
            File ppath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(ppath+"/ABC");
            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.filelist);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

}

Comment: Depending on how you built your listview, I would expect that you can either get the index of the clicked element and look that up in the data you created it from, or get its text and turn that back into a path, yes.  One thing you should not do though is get the index and then re-scan the disk to look it up, as the disk could have changed by inserting/removing something else in between when you created the listview and when it is clicked, resulting in your index being off.

Comment: but how can i do this ? i have searched for many tutorials but nothing seems to be helpful .um new to android .can u help @chris

Comment: Edit the code which creates your listview into the body of your question.

Comment: I have edited the code ..kindly check it

Comment: can i use this??? yourAdapter.getItem(pos); but how can i convert it into path?

Comment: The click listener goes in your post as well, not in a comment.

Comment: Oopz sorry it was my mistake .. i have edited my comment

Comment: You should be able to get the text from the item.  If that is a full path name you are all set, if it is just the file name then you will have to prepend the rest of the path as you original used when getting the list of files.  Consider adding some logging so you can see what is going on.  I expect you can probably write your own answer for this.

Comment: yeah um getting it .. thnx :) i will do it